# QT Webengine for Ubuntu

Tags: python, qt, ubuntu, qtwebengine

I have several different qt packages installed for my development environment on Ubuntu 15.04 (3.19.0-51-generic), and I can't seem to get my imports correct. The error I am running into in PyCharm is:

```
   from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

The following packages I have installed already, which I believe to be relevant are as follows:

```
python3-pyqt5
python3-pyqt5-dbg
python-pyqt5
python-pyqt5-dbg
pyqt5-dev-tools
pyqt5-dev
python-pyqt5.qtwebkit
python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
python-pyqt5.qtwebkit-dbg
python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit-dbg
```

What am I missing here? Note that the project explicitly requires the following in its README:

```
Qt 5.5+
PyQt5.6+
```

Furthermore, I understand that webengine and webkit are two different things (I was giving it a stab). I can't find any Webengine for PyQT5 anywhere in the official Vivid repository. I tried installing `libqt5webengine5-dev` and `libqt5webengine5` from [https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum-qt](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum-qt%22This%20PPA%22) packages with the same result, perhaps I need to add something to Python path. Can anyone lend a hand (Im normally a .NET developer :/)?

Comment: The problem you have is that the pyqt5 packages you have installed weren't built against a qt which included the webengine libs. So you will probably need re-compile pyqt5 from source yourself (unless you can find the relevant packages elsewhere).

Comment: This is helpful, thank you